# Copying JWT claims to header using istio ingress/gateway

Tags: istio, istio-gateway

I'm trying to implement adding JWT claims as request headers, using the undocumented `DYNAMIC_METADATA` feature as mentioned in [this github issue comment](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/35108#issuecomment-916547087) and explained in more detail as an 'existing solution' in [this google doc feature proposal](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1eJ4sPt5-fbXytSwov7senndMsrq4Et6qNYQKicLGHDs/edit). By the way, is there a place where these feature proposals are tracked? I would like to get more information about the state of this proposal, is it anywhere on the roadmap?

The specific part I'm talking about this this:

> Solution 3: Use an undocumented feature in VirtualService
> Istio VirtualService supports setting headers from dynamic attributes using the DYNAMIC_METADATA key. This can be combined with the JWT metadata to copy claims to headers.
> See example below
>
> ```
> apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
> kind: VirtualService
> metadata:
>   name: reviews-route
> spec:
>   hosts:
>   - reviews.prod.svc.cluster.local
>   http:
>   - headers:
>       request:
>         set:
>           # Copy the group claim to the x-istio-jwt-group header
>           x-istio-jwt-group:
>             '%DYNAMIC_METADATA(["istio_authn", "request.auth.claims", "group"])%'
> ```

As a POC, I have deployed an app which listens on `/echo-header` and will echo back the value of the `whatever-id` header of any request it receives. The app is called `web` and has an accompanying `kind: Service` called `web-svc`. I have configured several `AuthorizationPolicy` resources and one `RequestAuthentication` resource to make it so that this service can only be accessed with a valid JWT. This part works as I get a 401 when I make a request without JWT or with expired JWT. A `VirtualService` and `Gateway` resource make the service available for external requests. So far so good.

My from from here on out is to copy the value of the `whatever-id` claim which exists on my JWT (verified on [jwt.io](http://jwt.io/)) into the `whatever-id` header.
I Have then modified the `VirtualService` as mentioned in the feature proposal like so:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: web
spec:
  hosts:
    - example.com
  gateways:
    - web-gateway
  http:
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: /
      route:
        - destination:
            host: web-svc
            port:
              number: 80
      headers:
        request:
          set:
            whatever-id: '%DYNAMIC_METADATA(["istio_authn", "request.auth.claims", "whatever-id"])%'
            # whatever-id: "testing"
```

This however does not work. I verified the header transformation part, by commenting/uncommenting the last 2 lines, after which I did the `testing` string back from my POC application. But when I use the config with the line that should copy the claim value into the header, the header is not set on the request.

When I set logging to `rbac:debug` I can see the following log when making a request:

```
2022-02-23T14:04:05.708454Z     debug   envoy rbac      checking request: requestedServerName: outbound_.80_._.web-svc.route-echo.svc.cluster.local, sourceIP: 172.16.36.22:50722, directRemoteIP: 172.16.36.22:50722, remoteIP: 172.16.36.35:0,localAddress: 172.16.36.57:80, ssl: uriSanPeerCertificate: spiffe://cluster.local/ns/istio-ingress/sa/istio-ingress, dnsSanPeerCertificate: , subjectPeerCertificate: , headers: ':authority', 'example.com'
':path', '/echo-header'
':method', 'GET'
':scheme', 'https'
... <removed irrelevant headers for brevity>
, dynamicMetadata: filter_metadata {
  key: "envoy.filters.http.jwt_authn"
  value {
    fields {
      key: "<redacted issuer url>"
      value {
        struct_value {
          ... <removed all irrelevant claims for brevity>
          fields {
            key: "whatever-id"
            value {
              string_value: "98a5b3ea-f5e7-4012-8cf5-9cfb5cf9e65f"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
filter_metadata {
  key: "istio_authn"
  value {
    fields {
      key: "request.auth.audiences"
      value {
        string_value: "account"
      }
    }
    fields {
      key: "request.auth.claims"
      value {
        struct_value {
          ... <removed all irrelevant claims for brevity>
          fields {
            key: "whatever-id"
            value {
              list_value {
                values {
                  string_value: "98a5b3ea-f5e7-4012-8cf5-9cfb5cf9e65f"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    fields {
      key: "request.auth.presenter"
      value {
        string_value: "poc"
      }
    }
    fields {
      key: "request.auth.principal"
      value {
        string_value: "<redacted>"
      }
    }
    fields {
      key: "request.auth.raw_claims"
      value {
        string_value: "<redacted>"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

First thing I noticed when looking at this, is that the `dynamicMetadata` (which I assumed can be accessed by using the `%DYNAMIC_METADATA()%` synxtax as mentioned in the solution) does not contain an `istio_authn` field, the only field it contains is the `envoy.filters.http.jwt_auth` field, which has the key value equal to the issuer URL of my JWT, and under the value belonging to that key, there is a `whatever-id` field, which has the value which I want to add to my header, so I tried changing the header value in my VirtualService to:

```
whatever-id: '%DYNAMIC_METADATA(["envoy.filters.http.jwt_authn", "<issuer url>", "whatever-id"])%'
```

Sadly this did not work either.

What I also noticed, is that the keys used in the solution (`"istio_authn", "request.auth.claims"`) are available under the `filter_metadata` property of the log (as opposed to the `dynamicMetadata` property).
So maybe it is possible to use another syntax to access those `filter_metadata` properties?

Environment details:

- Kubernetes version 1.22.6
- Using Azure AKS
- Istio 1.13.0 deployed using helm chart

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes and Istio did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak added details to the bottom of question, thanks for responding!

Comment: Looks like you can do that with an envoy filter of type `envoy.filters.http.jwt_authn`: https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/9716

Comment: @Chris Thanks for your comment, it sounds like that should work, however I don't see how I can translate the envoy config from the github issue you linked, into a piece of Istio config, presumably I should use the [EnvoyFilter](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/envoy-filter/) config object, but I don't see how to match the 2 together :(

Comment: Could you update your yaml files after trying this hint from github?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak you mean the github link posted by @Chris? As I said in my last comment:
>I don't see how I can translate the envoy config from the github issue you linked, into a piece of Istio config, presumably I should use the EnvoyFilter config object, but I don't see how to match the 2 together